# How to decorate an ASP.NET MVC controller with Simple Injector

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simple-injector

I'd like to apply some cross-cutting concerns to my MVC controllers. At the moment, this is implemented through an abstract base class, but as we are refactoring more of the code base to take advantage of dependency injection, I'm wondering if this is something Simple Injector can help me with through its decoration or interception facilities.

So I've attempted to create a pretty basic decorator:

```
public class ControllerDecorator : IController
{
    private readonly IController _controller;

    public ControllerDecorator(IController controller)
    {
        _controller = controller;
    }

    public void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        // Do something of a cross-cutting nature here...

        _controller.Execute(requestContext);
    }
}
```

And in my composition root: `container.RegisterDecorator<IController, ControllerDecorator>()`

However, the code in my decorator's `Execute` method doesn't seem to ever get called. Is it because the MVC framework directly resolves my controller classes instead of going through `IController`? In that case, what can I do? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the default configuration, you can't apply decorators to controllers. The reason for this is that MVC's `DefaultControllerFactory` requests controllers by their concrete type. Because it requests a concrete type, Simple Injector is unable to apply a decorator; it has to assume that the caller needs this concrete type and has to therefore return this exact type (or a sub type).

To fix this, you will have to replace the default `DefaultControllerFactory` with a custom one:

```
public class SimpleInjectorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {
    public IDictionary<Type, InstanceProducer> Producers { get; set; }
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext rc, Type type) {
        return (IController)this.Producers[type].GetInstance();
    }
}
```

Next, in your bootstrapper, you'll have to replace the call to `RegisterMvcControllers` with the following:

```
var controllerTypes = SimpleInjectorMvcExtensions.GetControllerTypesToRegister(
    container, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

var controllerProducers = controllerTypes
    .ToDictionary(type => type, type => CreateControllerProducer(container, type));

// Verify after creating the controller producers.
container.Verify();

ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
    new SimpleInjectorControllerFactory { Producers = controllerProducers });
```

The `CreateControllerProducer` method looks as follows:

```
private static InstanceProducer CreateControllerProducer(Container c, Type type) {
    var producer = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer(typeof(IController), type, c);
    producer.Registration.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(
        DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent,
        "MVC disposes the controller when the web request ends.");
    return producer;
}
```

The crucial part is that the call to `CreateProducer` is supplied with `typeof(IController)`; this allows Simple Injector to apply a decorator for `IController`.

This is it; now you can register your decorator for `IController`.

One warning though: with both Web API and the new ASP.NET core it is impossible to apply decorators to controllers. Both frameworks expect concrete types; they will break if you wrap the real controller. The preferred way with those frameworks to decorate controllers is through the OWIN pipeline. So this answer solely works with MVC 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had to make one change to the code, however: in the call to `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory`, I had to use the `controllerFactory` instance created before container verification. If not instantiating it before the `Verify` call I'd get a diagnostic warning error; if instantiating it again in the `SetControllerFactory` method as well, nothing happens and the decorator is never applied. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @MartinWedvich ah yes, of course. The controller factory suppresses the diagnostics. You obvoiusly need to suppres it before verifying

Comment: After the call to `container.Verify`, the producers in `controllerProds` have been mutated from the controller classes (such as `HomeController`) to `ControllerDecorator`, and it appears that this is the reason why it's failing if I new up the factory the second time. Is this intended behavior?

Comment: Not sure what you are saying, but you need to register the decorator before calling Verify or resolving anything. The order in which you do things should not matter.

Comment: I have a `HomeController`. Using your code, before the call to `container.Verify`, the `controllerProds` contains a producer where the `ImplementationType` property is set to `HomeController`. After the call to `container.Verify`, this producer has its `ImplementationType` set to `ControllerDecorator` (which is the name of my controller decorator class). Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: @MartinWedvich: Yes, it is supposed to happen. The same will happen when you call `GetInstance()` on that `InstanceProducer`. You can also call `InstanceProducer.VisualizeObjectGraph()` to see the complete graph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87591/discussion-between-martin-wedvich-and-steven).