# Simple Injector registering same interface with different constructor arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, simple-injector

I'm using simple injector with my MVC application.
I'm injecting my Entity Framework DbContext into my MVC Controllers but one specific controller needs to initialize the DbContext with optional arguments (e.g ownsConnection:false).

Can I register multiple times the same interface with different constructor arguments? How would I achieve this?

```
   public static void Initialize()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
        InitializeContainer(container);
        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        container.Verify();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IDbContext>(() => new DbContext("ConnectionString"), Lifestyle.Scoped);
    }
```

For a specific controller I need to inject DbContext with argument contextOwnsConnection:false

Comment: The `DbContext` should be in initialised in the Composition Root before being passed into any Controller. Can you show some skeleton code?

Comment: Can you explain why it is you need to have a controller with a dbcontext that doesn't own its connection?

Comment: @Steven I have a controller which has an "ugly" mix of EF and Ado.Net nested transactions (sqlfilestream). EF6 doc (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx) Advices to start a sql connection and then tell EF to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decorate your controller to customize its resolution. But you cannot do tha  directly. [Look here](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mvcintegration.html), that refers to this SO question: [How to decorate an ASP.NET MVC controller with Simple Injector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118849/how-to-decorate-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-with-simple-injector).

Then have a look at this technique [Intercepting the Creation of Types](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection)