# Using interceptor for asp.net controller using Simple Injector

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aop, simple-injector

I'm trying to add an interceptor for all of my controllers. I'm using Simple Injector and asp.net MVC.

While trying this example: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/InterceptionExtensions.html everything worked when I wanted to add the interceptor to an interface. The problem starts with Controllers since they are concrete type and not interfaces...

```
private static void ThrowIfServiceTypeNotInterface(ExpressionBuiltEventArgs e)  {
    // NOTE: We can only handle interfaces, because
    // System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy only supports interfaces.
    if (!e.RegisteredServiceType.IsInterface) {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Can't intercept type " +
                    e.RegisteredServiceType.Name + " because it is not an interface.");
    }
}
```

In the implementation above there is an explicit restriction to interfaces only, I would like to understand why?

Does anyone have experience in adding interceptors to SimpleInjector for Controllers / concrete types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the implementation above there is an explicit restriction to interfaces only, I would like to understand why?

Well, the comment already answers that question:

```
// NOTE: We can only handle interfaces, because
// System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy only supports interfaces.
```

To be able to apply interception, you will have to make sure that the controllers are resolved by the `IController` interface. You will find how to achieve this in this q/a: [How to decorate an ASP.NET MVC controller with Simple Injector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118849/how-to-decorate-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-with-simple-injector).